# js function called by content updated via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got a div which is updated via AJAX(result is passed in other php page), and the content is a table with buttons, which should call a js function with value passed on:

```
<?php echo '
<table>
<tr>
 <td>115</td>
 <td><input type="button" value="down" onclick="jsFunction(115)"/></td>
</tr>
</table>'; ?>
```

The div gets updated with function `filter()` as follows(also i pass to `filter()` different values, but when loaded, it starts with value 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
filter(1);
});

function filter(pageval) {  
var user = document.getElementById("user");
userval = user.value;
var pid= '#page-'+pageval;

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'filtercase.php',
    data: {
     user:userval,
     page: pageval,
    },
    success: function (response) {
    $( '#ajax-response' ).html(response);
    }
});
}
```

**Question: where do I put jsFunction(int) so it will be called only when button is table is clicked?**

Function itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadReport(case){
    console.log(case);}
</script>
```

I've put it in `$(document).ready(function())`, as independent script on the bottom of the page, inside my ajax response - none worked:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token case
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError:downloadReport is not defined

Comment: `case` being a reserved keyword, the javascript engine does not read your code function at all. You have the error in the console... So?

Comment: This is correct.  Instead of 'case', maybe 'data'.  Also, where is jsFunction defined?

Comment: @jdmayfield, that is the question, where should I put it?

Comment: Instead of passing the value to downloadReport, you could have downloadReport 'get' the elements data via document.getElementById or similar.

Comment: Actually, @Pierre, I changed my variable name, and it worked, Thx! If you'd add it as an answer, I'd accept that

Comment: @upicik I added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case` being a reserved keyword, the javascript engine does not read your code function at all.

You have the error in the console...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a handler.  The simple way is to add to your button element:

```
onclick="downloadReport()"
```